# python distutils.core setup() package directory does not exist

Tags: python

I am trying to install the [following](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQUIK) package but it fails with the following error:

```
error: package directory 'pyquik' does not exist
```

The package has the following structure and all files seem to be present there:

```
pyquik/
    __init__.py
    ...(other files)
setup.py
```

The contents of `setup.py` is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='PyQUIK',
    version='1.0',
    description='Python to QUIK Connector',
    long_description='Wrapper for TRANS2QUIK.dll (version 1.1) library.',
    packages=['pyquik'],
    package_data={'pyquik': ['TRANS2QUIK.dll']},
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        ...
    ],
    license='BSD',
)
```

Any ideas how to fix the error would be welcome. Thank you.

**UPD_1**

the command `pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/75/e7/263baf34aff56e8e49c04‌​b33067f790b181094b3d‌​588d97ae23024470a06/‌​PyQUIK-1.0.zip #md5=8d05e9075b27587fb44eea420f777f20` fails with the folloowing errors: `error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3v52\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\_‌​_init__.py'` and also `error: could not create 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3v52\Lib\site-packages\pyquik': ╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях`

the command `conda install https://pypi.python.org/packages/75/e7/263baf34aff56e8e49c04‌​b33067f790b181094b3d‌​588d97ae23024470a06/‌​PyQUIK-1.0.zip #md5=8d05e9075b27587fb44eea420f777f20` fails with the following: `PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 channels:` although it is definetely there

Comment: Why not use pip to install the package?

Comment: I am using PyCharm IDE wth Anaconda3 as a compiler and set of packages. Could you please advice how to install the package wth PIP in my environment?

Comment: I don't use anaconda, but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164986/i-dont-know-how-to-install-package-in-anaconda) may help.

Comment: says `PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: ` though it is definetely there

Comment: Which exact commands are you running? Perhaps also from which directory? Can you add this informations in your question?

Comment: the command `pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/75/e7/263baf34aff56e8e49c04b33067f790b181094b3d588d97ae23024470a06/PyQUIK-1.0.zip
#md5=8d05e9075b27587fb44eea420f777f20` fails with the folloowing errors: `error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3v52\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\__init__.py'` and also `error: could not create 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3v52\Lib\site-packages\pyquik': ╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях`

Comment: You may need to run the command as administrator to bypass the permission issue. Alternatively, you could try with `pip install --user ...`